# live search jquery (searching in li title)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to search with an input field a list of items,

```
<ul class="display">
 <li title="Pizza Otto">some divs</li>
 <li title="Pizza Prono">some divs</li>
 <li title="Pizza David">some divs</li>
</ul>
```

The code below works fine for words in the `<li>...</li>` I want to put there some divs and to add a title attribute to `<li>` where to make the search.

```
$('input[name="q"]').search('.display li', function(on) {
    on.all(function(results) {
        var size = results ? results.size() : 0
        $('#count').text(size + ' results');
});
```

Any idea for the right selector here: `.search('.display li'`?  Or where I have to make the changes?

Thanks and sorry for my English...

P.S. Is my first question here!

UPDATE: function to test if the val is contained

```
 function query(selector) {
    if (val = this.val()) {
      return $(selector + ':contains("' + val + '")');;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: so you want to search through the titles and select the one that matches the input value?

Comment: Yes. the titles save in <li> tag and show only the <li> that matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the search method... but

```
var result=$('.display li["title='+$('input[name="q"]').val()+'"]');
```

would select the li you're looking for

I think @robin-pyon was thinking of the :contains() selector, the .contains() method actually searches for a dom element inside of another dom element, if the text you want to search is contained in the LI you can use this to select the ui:

```
var result=$('.display li:contains("'+$('input[name="q"]').val()+'")');
```

Comment: thanks for your advice! it works just like i wanted. @robin-pyon told me that i can use .contains () to show also the li that contains what i search for... how the code will change to do that? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Provided you just want to highlight list items that match your input value, you could also try use `.contains()` (if you want a partial match), otherwise you could use the attribute contains selector that Trey mentioned.

An example of both, including a case-insensitive `.contains()` can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sV6et/).

Comment: like the case insensitive extention:) +1